# how to create a map base on the user coordinates?

Tags: mapkit, coordinates, xcode4.3

How do I create an app that would takes map coordinates & map size enter by a user, and then draws that desired map? I looked, couldn't fine any video either. All the map tutorial show is how to create a app for your current location.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples you've found are totally valid, you only need to provide the coordinates of the map you want to display in addition to that. That's the easy part...

It's usually as easy as

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake (60,0,1.5, 1.5);
[mapView setRegion: region];
```